# Is it possible to install different versions of the same Nuget package into different branches of the code?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, git-branch

So for example, we can start a branch for a new version and use updated Nuget packages only in that branch while keeping the master branch on a trusted/stable package version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to install different versions of the same Nuget package into different branches of the code?

Of course you can.

But you need to pay attention when you merge with your master branch. This is the worth of the branch. It just like you update the nuget version in the different branches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I assumed. But I end up with the same package in master branch and new version branch. What am I missing here?

Comment: OK it seems I had a deeper problem in that Visual Studio wasn't managing my branches at all, even though they existed and I could switch between them in name at least. Any change I made in any branch was appearing in all branches, including updated nuget packageds. In other words there were no real branches created . So I completely removed the local repo (taking care to save recent code changes). Then from VS cloned the project I wanted and then from VS created the new branches. Everything worked as expected this time around.